# Phoenix primary key does not link to Row key in HBase

Tags: hbase, apache-phoenix

I have created a table using Phoenix command prompt and it is working fine.
CREATE TABLE CUSTOMERS (ID INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, NAME VARCHAR(40),  CITY CHAR(25));
I'm facing following issues.

1. Primary Key ID created above  does not represent Rowkey in Hbase  Table.  How I should create Phoenix tables whose Primary Key will point to RowKey in HBase?
2. Describe Table in Phoenix does not show column data type. Where I can get that info please?

Thanks,
Abhishek

Answer (score 1):

!describe CUSTOMERS; will describe the columns. If you insert data into table, you can find out that id is mapped to rowid. You can observe this better when you use rowid as varchar rather than int.